# How to extend XMLHttpRequest object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I would like to extend the existing `XMLHttpRequest` object so that it should work with all the browsers. Now I have been trough with [JS inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) and things however before starting I would like to see good example of it.

HTML5 has upload and progress events stuff which I would like to implement in inherited new object which can behave even if the feature is not supported by not introducing JS errors to client side. So I would like to achieve something like this:

```
Class XMLHttpRequest{}
Class UploadXMLHttpRequest: XMLHttpRequest{}
```

Where additional methods can be attached to `UploadXMLHttpRequest` class like following.

```
UploadXMLHttpRequest.prototype.uploadFile = function(file){

}
```

Considering YUI, jQuery and others are good in market no one really wants to do this made it little difficult for me to find good resources.

Comment: unatainable goal since not all browsers have a XMLHttpRequest class. and by not all browsers, I mean Internet explorer. What you have to do is to use those 'good in market' libraries and use their wrappers to make your ajax calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to override the getResponseHeader method on XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581959/failed-to-override-the-getresponseheader-method-on-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: No i know ActiveXObject in IE and XMLHttpRequest in others. What i would like to know is what is good way i can extend the XMLHttpRequest so that i can have a clean and safe API for regular use.

Comment: Look at code of "good in market" libraries =)

Comment: You can use the frameworks previously named, they have a clean safe, widely used and tested API, so unless you have good reasons, in which case it would be could to expose them here, why wouldn't you use them ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this. `XMLHttpRequest` is a host object and you should not try to extend it. To quote [Kangax](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/#host_objects_have_no_rules):

> Next problem with DOM extension is
>   that **DOM objects are host objects**, and
>   host objects are the worst bunch. By
>   specification (ECMA-262 3rd. ed), host
>   objects are allowed to do things, no
>   other objects can even dream of. To
>   quote relevant section <sup>[[8.6.2]](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2)</sup>:
>
> > *Host objects may implement these
> >     internal methods with any
> >     implementation-dependent behaviour, or
> >     it may be that a host object
> >     implements only some internal methods
> >     and not others.*

This also means that host objects may disallow extension by using `prototype`.

However, as Kangax also [advices](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/#wrappers_to_the_rescue), you can create a wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest` and do whatever you like with it.

Comment: I fully agree, and would have written a similar answer. Also, ActiveX `XMLHttpRequest` objects (as available in IE, and preferred over native `XMLHttpRequest` objects in jQuery) definitely do not allow extension.

Comment: Thanks for nice and complete answer.