# XMLHttpRequest response alter callback

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My question is: is any(even not best, but worked) way in JavaScript to change every response data before it will be processed by another callbacks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes you can. The method will depend on how you are doing this request. What I would do is to override the method that handle the requests with your own code and then call the standard one. This is called [Mokey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

Also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931977/how-to-extend-xmlhttprequest-object-in-javascript).