# XHR (Ajax) send prototype strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to overrule the send method of an ajax method. See my code below:

```
(function() {
    var beforeCall = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
        sendCall = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        console.log("OPEN"); // Works

        // Only called once, but Ajax has 5 states, which are should log 5 times
        this.onreadystatechange = function(){ console.log("READYSTATE SOMETHING"); } 

        return beforeCall.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    };

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        var origCallback = this.onreadystatechange;
        this.onreadystatechange = function(){
            console.log("ONREADYSTATECHANGE"); // This log never gets called
            if( origCallback ) {
                origCallback.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments))
            }
        };
        return sendCall.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    }
})();
```

The OPEN is logged, the READYSTATE SOMETHING is logged only once, but should log each state? Then on my send function I try to overwrite it again (should be here, because maybe my website already has a onreadystatechange and I don't want to lose that callback. So, I need it there but that callback never gets called.

The original functionality still works with my code above. But I don't get the extra log which I want.

Anyone knows why my onreadystatechange with the `console.log("ONREADYSTATECHANGE")` never gets called?

The site I need this code for is using jQuery atm, but it should also work with native Javascript Ajax.

Comment: Updated my answer, made a mistake in FireFox. Error in your code cannot be re produced in FireFox 33.0 unless running it in a console of a fresh new tab that doesn't have a page open. I am curious what the updated code in my answer would produce for you in other browser (I only have FireFox and Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

It seems `beforeCall.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));` causes an error in FireFox:

```
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    console.log("OPEN"); // Works

    // Only called once, but Ajax has 5 states, which are should log 5 times
    this.onreadystatechange = function(){ console.log("READYSTATE SOMETHING"); } 
    console.log('still ok here');
    var ret = beforeCall.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));//error here
    console.log('this is not happening');
    return ret;//neither does this
};
```

It works in Chrome 32.0.1700.107

Maybe this is because XMLHttpRequest is a host object and the open function does not behave like a normal JS function should behave, maybe the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4932156/1641941) is still relevant.

This could be just a FireFox bug but it would mean it's impossible to listen to any open and send invocations on any XMLHttpRequest. You can create a wrapper and use that wrapper to invoke XHR request but then you only capture open and send from your code; not from 3rd party code

**[UPDATE]**

Seems that I made a mistake.

Running the following code in firebug console (FireFox 33) when having google.com open works for me, it doesn't work in a fresh new tab though; have to visit a site.

```
(function() {
    var beforeCall = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
        sendCall = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function open() {
        var ret;
        console.log("OPEN");
        this.onreadystatechange = function(){ console.log("READYSTATE SOMETHING"); } 
        console.log('open still working');
        ret = beforeCall.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
        console.log('open is done');
        return ret;
    };

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function send() {
        console.log('this is send');
        var origCallback = this.onreadystatechange,ret;
        this.onreadystatechange = function(){
            console.log("ONREADYSTATECHANGE");
            if( origCallback ) {
                origCallback.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments))
            }
        };
        console.log('send still working');
        ret = sendCall.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
        console.log('send done');
        return ret;
    }
})();

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET','/');
//calling xhr.open with wrong order of parameters gives a not so elegant error
//xhr.open('/','GET')
xhr.send();
```